# References for computing mass diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, regularization

I'm currently attempting to compute the amplitude of the shown diagram following as a guide Peskin's calculations of the electron self-energy.

[image]

The problem is that in the given result of this diagram:

[image]

there's no cut-off term to be seen, which throws me off even more.

I'm looking for better worked-out examples close to this one than the electron self-energy. Any other form of guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of radiative mass diagrams can be found in models like the Scotogenic, proposed by E. Ma, linking dark matter and neutrino mass. In simple words, it is just a 1-loop realization of the Weinberg operator: two leptons and two SM-Higgs bosons.

You can find the details of the calculation of the same type of diagram for this model in Appendix A of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.00481) paper by De Romeri, Puerta, and Vicente. You can also take a look at [this](http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:517225/FULLTEXT01) MSc. thesis, section 2.2.2, by R. Bouchand.

Even though these two references show the calculation in the context of the Scotogenic model, the procedure is quite generic for any other theory with similar interactions.